# Printing a function and its parameters as a string

Tags: python, function

I have a function which looks like this:

```
function_dictionary = {'get_user_from_id': (requests.get,                           #Function
                                           (url + "/users/" + str(user_id),),       #Tuple of Arguments
                                           {'headers': headers}),                   #Dictionary of keyword args

                           'get_user_from_username': (requests.get,
                                            (url + "/users?username=" + str(user_id),),
                                            {'headers': headers}),

                           'get_user_from_email': (requests.get,
                                         (url + "/users?email=" + str(user_id),),
                                         {'headers': headers}),

                           'delete': (requests.delete,
                                      (url + "/users/" + str(user_id),),
                                      {'headers': headers}),

                           'patch_user':(requests.patch,
                                         (url + "/users/" + str(user["ID"]),),
                                         {'headers': headers, 'data':json.dumps(user)}),

                           'post': (requests.post,
                                    (url + "/users" ,),
                                    {'headers': headers,'data':json.dumps(user)})
                           }

func, args, kwargs = function_dictionary[request]

func(*args, **kwargs)

result = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need to record the exact line of code which is about to be executed. In a perfect world, I am looking for something like this:

```
print func(*args, **kwargs).toString or str(func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Does anybody know if what I am trying to do is possible or should I focus on just building a string myself?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, you can simply do

```
print func.func_name, args, kwargs
```

I would write a generic decorator, if I am defining the functions myself, like this

```
def decorate_logger(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Entering", func.func_name, "with Parameters :", args, kwargs
        temp = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Leaving ", func.func_name, "with :", temp, "for :", args, kwargs
        return temp
    return inner

@decorate_logger
def sum(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

print sum(1, 2, 3)
print sum(1, 2, c = 3)
```

**Output**

```
Entering sum with Parameters : (1, 2, 3) {}
Leaving  sum with : 6 for : (1, 2, 3) {}
6
Entering sum with Parameters : (1, 2) {'c': 3}
Leaving  sum with : 6 for : (1, 2) {'c': 3}
6
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to add much over `print func.__name__, args, kwargs`, and certainly isn't "the exact line of code which is about to be executed".

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yup. For his case, the first print is enough. But if he is defining those functions, then he might want to decorate it like this. We don't have to explicitly print things.